# Can't capture video with cheese. Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: webcam, asus, cheese

On my Asus N61DA Notebook with built-in webcamera no possibility to capture video with cheese. Shooting photos fine, but when pushing "record a video" button, application freezes for a few seconds and then quit. Terminal says: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

In Skype everything working fine with my webcam.

In guvcview my webcam showing only half of image from up to down. The second half of image is black/blank from the middle of my screen to the bottom. Capture video in guvcview also impossible. Seems to be it'is recording something but when done, i'm running this video and there no sounds buy only animation like in windows media player some kind of screensaver.

Answer (score 3):

I've expirienced exactly the same problems both with *cheese* and *guvcview* using Assus N43SN webcam this morning and with bit of research it came out that the issues is related to this one: [cheese crashed with SIGSEGV in **GI**_libc_free()](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/1062282).

So installing the missing dependency package `gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio` solved the problem for me.

To install the package run the following in your terminal, to open the terminal hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

Good luck!